# How to get the overlay to display for jquery ui modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-confirmation.html), the overlay is displayed correctly and all elements underneath the overlay are disabled:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1920px; height: 650px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

However, when I use the code in my page, I can still access the other controls underneath the overlay.  Any ideas on how to fix?  I've been looking at the documentation and don't see much regarding overlay implementation.

My code:

```
$("<div title='" + title + "'><div class='ui-state-error ui-corner-all'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert'></span><strong>Error: </strong>" + message + "</p></div></div>").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false
    });
```

Comment: Are you including the jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: Think so, you mean this right:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type='text/css' media='all' />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the zIndex on the dialog to a high number to get around this:

```
$("<div title='" + title + "'><div class='ui-state-error ui-corner-all'><p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert'></span><strong>Error: </strong>" + message + "</p></div></div>").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    zIndex: 100000,
    draggable: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  *smacking my forehead*